# Is there a way to rebind keys?

Tags: sword-of-the-stars-the-pit

I was wondering if there's a way to rebind the keys in Sword of the Stars: The Pit, because I can't seem to find any way to. If there isn't a way, have the developers given any indication that there will be a way to rebind the keys in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you enter the game, in the main menu go to **Options**. In there you can rebind the keys. After you change them click on the ***Save*** and confirm, otherwise they will reset each time you start the game.

[image]

Comment: *head desk* i am blind tyvm